# Sqlite3 command won't execute

Tags: select, sqlite, return

My problem is that I have a program working with some sql statement

```
 const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT lastPlayed FROM Settings;";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)    {
        NSLog(@"database error");
    }
    if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW){
...
    }
```

My problem is that with this sql command it will write to the nslog that database error and it won't get into the body of my if to work with the statement... if I change the sql statement to select name from Session LIMIT ? , ? and bind the two number it will work just fine. I tested the sql command in sqlite manager and working just fine... any help? what could be the problem?

Update1: found out that it says that no such table: Settings even though I have it... maybe it's the problem of xCode? it wouldn't update the simulator?

Update2 Solved: the source of the problem was the simulator.... I had to delete the cache... thx for fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `sqlite3_errmsg` API function to get the error message and print that to the log. That will tell you what the problem is.
2. You don't need `;` in the statement, because that just tells `sqlite3_prepate_v2` to ignore anything after it (it returns pointer to where it ended in the last argument to facilitate running sql scripts), but that's not causing problems.